# What happened to Gandalf the Grey's body when he was sent back as Gandalf the White?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, gandalf

So Gandalf and the Balrog of Moria have a little fisticuffs and they both died. Presumably dead bodies lie on the mountain side somewhere.

Gandalf "strayed out of thought and time", gets a can of spinach and a new colour then he comes back sometime after his death as Gandalf 2.0.

The questions are thus:

1. Did Gandalf's old body get burnt to a crisp, or suffer some other death that meant there was no dead body left? OR
2. Did his old body get renewed?

Or do we not know? If his body was left in the snow, then wouldn't it have been preserved due to freezing? This seems like an obvious oversight in the story.

I'd like to stick with the book canon, but out-of universe answers are also welcome.

**Clarification: I'm not asking about his soul or whether he can die or where he went. I am specifically asking about what was left behind on the mountain.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can the Valar or Maiar die?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7932/can-the-valar-or-maiar-die) The tl;dr: the Valar and Maiar don't have mortal bodies in the same way as Men, Dwarves, etc., but *clothe* themselves in mortal form. Notice what happened to Sauron and Saruman on dying.

Comment: @Lexible Nope. I want to know what happened to his body. Did he wake up next to his old one and freak out or not? Saurons body wasn't like Gandalfs. This is mention in some other answer.

Comment: Per my comment: Maiar (including Gandalf) don't *have* bodies, except as "clothes."

Comment: @Lexible I think your wrong. Sauron did not have a body but Gandalf was given one ... two actually.

Comment: see this answer for a reference to Gandalfs body: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/13405/7614  "they were embodied in physical bodies capable of pain, and weariness, and of afflicting the spirit with physical fear, and of being 'killed', though supported by the angelic spirit they might endure long, and only show slowly the wearing of care and labour."

Comment: And Saurons body is his own consstruct: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/12746/7614

Comment: Fair, but there's more about it on the dupe link. (Right: "Own construct" = soul clothes.)

Comment: @Lexible Sauron is not Gandalf. the link is about Sauron and whether he can die. I was asking about Gandalfs Dead body. I'm not sure how I can make this any clearer.

Comment: Sauron is a Maia. So is Gandalf (and the other Istari).

Comment: @Lexible This is the last thing I will say on the issue: Gandalfs body is not the same as Saurons. Even Sauruman left behind bones and skin as per the question you linked.

Comment: [This question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/51949/would-gandalf-have-been-promoted-to-the-white-if-he-had-not-fought-the-balrog) presumes Gandalf's body was destroyed in the fight with the Balrog - is there a reason you assume Gandalf the Grey and the Balrog's bodies are just lying next to each other?

Comment: @robotnik i didn't assume they were next to each other just on the same mountain side?

Comment: The real question is if Gandalf 2.0 can die from a another round of fisticuffs.  I love the wording of your question!

Comment: It was washed in new intensified Tide!  :-)

Comment: He would have to go and find his Elven Ring of Power regardless, so it was a good thing they re-used the body.  Be embarrassing to tell Elrond and Galadriel he'd lost it.

Comment: @Lexible - the OP's points are correct here; see the Istari essay in Unfinished Tales: "For with the consent of Eru they sent members of their own high order, but **clad in bodies of as of Men, real and not feigned**, but subject to the fears and pains and weariness of earth, able to hunger and thirst and be slain".  This constraint doesn't apply to Sauron, so you're not comparing like-with-like here.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The book suggests that his spirit reinhabited his original body, and there seems no reason to suspect otherwise.

First let's look at the deaths of both Gandalf and the Balrog (quotes from the Two Towers chapter *the White Rider*):

> I threw down my enemy, and he fell from the high place and broke the mountain-side where he smote it in his ruin. Then darkness took me; and I strayed out of thought and time, and I wandered far on roads that I will not tell.

Then Gandalf's resurrection:

> Naked I was sent back – for a brief time, until my task is done. And naked I lay upon the mountain-top. The tower behind was crumbled into dust, the window gone; the ruined stair was choked with burned and broken stone. I was alone, forgotten, without escape upon the hard horn of the world.

This makes it clear that he was resurrected in the same place where he had died, but - of course - his body *could* have been remade.  However, and a little further on in the text, we learn that after Gwaihir brought him to Lórien:

> I tarried there in the ageless time of that land where days bring healing not decay. Healing I found, and I was clothed in white.

Evidently therefore his body needed healing, which we can reasonably suppose it would not have if it was a new body.  Hence we can deduce that it was his original body, not renewed.

If we cross-check this with Letter 156 we see confirmation of the "Gandalf needed healing" hypothesis:

> Galadriel's power is not divine, and his healing in Lórien is meant to be no more than physical healing and refreshment.

So there is no oversight in the story; Gandalf evidently just reinhabited his old body, which then needed to be healed of it's wounds in Lórien.

Comment: I had missed the part about him needing healing. I only thought he had a new body because he was naked. I guess he threw off his clothes in the fight?

Comment: @JamesKhoury Or they were burned off while he was fighting the fire monster. But, yeah, deliberately taking off his clothes in the middle of the fight makes more sense.

Comment: He dies on 25 Jan, comes back to life 15 Feb and by 1 March (all TA 3019) is out in Fanghorn meeting up with Aragorn, Gimli & Legolas ([nifty reference](http://lotrproject.com/timeline/#zoom=2&lat=-1658&lon=1500&layers=BTT)). Seems like a fast healer to me ;)

Comment: @KyleKanos - or he recieved fast healing from the Elves.

Comment: Maybe Gandalf, delivered naked to Lorien, received a "special kind" of healing from Galadriel? (Cue Marvin Gaye singing "Sexual Healing").

Comment: For what it's worth, the movie has a *very* brief flashback where Gandalf is lying on the ground and gasps, presumably resuming breathing. He's even not wearing a shirt, iirc. (Always thought that was a bit weird.) That would suggest the movies fairly accurately reflects the book here. Although, this raises a question. What the heck happened to his clothes that he was naked when he came back?

Comment: [Resurrection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resurrection#Christianity) is also rather an important part of Tolkien's Roman Catholic worldview. Cf. [Matthew 28](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+28), [Luke 24](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%2024) and many others.

Comment: @Nathan Except Tolkien **HATED** allegory.

Comment: @krillgar it's not allegorical at all, just analogous. Cf. somewhere in LoTR there's a conversation about "the heathen burn the dead but we give them a proper burial"

Comment: Maybe he needed healing because he caught cold being frikin naked at mountain-top during winter

Comment: I always though that "naked" referred to him being "remade or "re-imagined", he was no longer Gandalf The Grey, the he was becoming Gandalf The White. Ergo he was naked, not so much without clothes, but without colour . . . but also, without clothes.