# Why did Gandalf become the white wizard?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

When Gandalf comes back alive after dying in *The Lord of the Rings*, why does he come back as the white wizard not the grey wizard? Am I correct that it is because Saruman had become evil?

Comment: Do you perhaps mean that it is because *Saruman* had become evil?

Comment: @Valorum Similar, but I'm not comfortable closing it; "Who" is not the same as "why", and Andres' answer doesn't really explain why Eru chose to bring him back

Comment: You mean Saruman not Sauron, right?

Comment: @JasonBaker Would http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/51949/would-gandalf-have-been-promoted-to-the-white-if-he-had-not-fought-the-balrog be a better dupe target?

Comment: @Randal'Thor I like that one better, but not enough to hammer it. I'm leaving it to the community to decide

Comment: Because the White Witch was [already taken](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_Witch).

Comment: Because they had the time to wash his robes for the first time in ages.

Answer (score 6):

Tolkien addresses this in Letter 156:

> [Gandalf] was the *only* person who could direct the resistance to Sauron successfully, and all *his* mission was vain.
>
> *[...]*
>
> The 'wizards', as such, had failed; or if you like: the crisis had become too grave and needed an enhancement of power. *[...]* [Gandalf] was sent by a mere prudent plan of the angelic Valar or governors; but Authority had taken up this plan and enlarged it, at the moment of its failure.
>
> <sup>*The Letters of J.R.R. Tolkien* 156: To Robert Murray, SJ (draft). November 1954</sup>

Gandalf's promotion was a decision [made by God](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/47085/31051) to offset the growing power of Sauron and the waning power of the Free Peoples of Middle-earth.

Comment: Is Eru/Illuvatar ever referred to as "God" with a capital G by Tolkein?

Comment: @ToddWilcox Not often, but occasionally; letter 131, for instance: "The cycles begin with a cosmogonical myth: the *Music of the Ainur*. God and the Valar (or powers: Englished as gods) are revealed." [This question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/124046/31051) is also instructive

Answer (score 1):

Gandalf came back as the white wizard because the current white wizard (Saruman) had turned his back on what the Istari were meant to be doing in Middle-earth and had joined Sauron in his goal of domination of Middle-earth.

Because Saruman had abandoned his purpose Eru appointed Gandalf to be the next white wizard. This allowed Gandalf to shatter Sarumans' staff and take the mantle of white wizard instead of grey. Becoming the white wizard meant that Gandalf was the head of the Istari sent to Middle-earth.

Comment: That's 'Saruman', not 'Sauruman'!

Comment: @vascowhite Well, the OP said Sauron instead of Saruman, so ...

Comment: Source for the ranking? I've never heard that bit before, only that Saruman was the first one sent and Gandalf was the last

Comment: @sharur not able to find anything conclusive at the moment except that Saruman the White was the most powerful http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Wizards will have a proper look when I get home... There is always the possibility that What I said is worng

Comment: @sharur I cannot seem to find any cannon source for power 'ranks' of the Istari  (except that White was the head of the order) only general conjecture and usually some level of agreement. In fact Tolkien seems to be deliberately vague on how much power the Istari have in comparison with each other. So I will remove that part from the answer I had.